"_SLINE OFF." error message whenever trying to use python in SPSS
I'm using spss 25 on a mac running mojave and get "_SLINE OFF." error message when trying to run any python, eg print "hello world".
I've done all the basic checks, the syntax is all ok. SPSS has the python directories saved correctly.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
